# How to get TradeCaptureReport (AE) message when using quickfixj?

Tags: java, quickfix, quickfixj, ice

I am sending a Trade capture report request with 35 = AD.  I am getting an acknowledge message back with 35=AQ(TradeCaptureReportRequestAck) with 750 =0 and another acknowledge message 35=AQ with 750=1.  However I am not getting any 35=AE(TradeCaptureReport) messages even though there are trades booked on ICE.
I am using quickfixj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the ICE FIX Trade Capture interface documentation.

If you don't see any AE messages in your message log, then they're not being sent to you.  If you get an AQ/750=0 followed by a AQ/750=1 with no AEs in between, that means you've successfully received a TCR set of size 0.

I am quite familiar with the ICE FIX Trade Capture API.  Their documentation is pretty good; please review it to make sure you understand how requests are honored.

Comment: There is a deal booked on ICE however I am not getting AE msg either in logs or application. I have gone through the ICE FIX Trade capture Reference Manual and done the implementation accordingly and could resolve other issues. But for this particular issue, I could not find the reason (as per the documentation , it is because there is no trade available which is not true in my case). Can you let me know if there is something else which I might be missing?

Comment: I think you're going to need to reach out to ICE.  I suspect your TCR request is not right, but that would be a message-content problem, not a QF-code problem.  Maybe your request has the wrong start-time/end-time parameters?

Comment: Thanks, booked another trade on ICE and it started flowing.

Comment: You didn't say what the cause actually was.

Comment: I did not make any change in code/config. I suspect ICE test team has not captured the trade. When I asked them to re-book the trade it started flowing to my application.

Answer (score 0):

As Grant pointed out it is important to differentiate between message received in log file and message received in your application. If the latter is not happening although you are seeing the messages in your log then you need to look at your MessageCracker implementation.

Comment: There is a deal booked on ICE however I am not getting AE msg either in logs or application. I have gone through the ICE FIX Trade capture Reference Manual and done the implementation accordingly and could resolve other issues. But for this particular issue, I could not find the reason (as per the documentation , it is because there is no trade available which is not true in my case). Can you please let me know if there is something else which I might be missing?